# Global fatal Handler is not invoked

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

I have register the error handler in my SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory, But handler is not called when I post the fatal message.
Code

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class ListenerContainerFactory {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ListenerContainerFactory.class);

    @Autowired
    RabbitMqConfig rabbitMqConfig;

    @Autowired
    EPPQ2Subscriber receiver;

    @Autowired
    EPPQ2ChanelAwareSubscriber receiverChanel;


     public ListenerContainerFactory(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
        printContainerStartMsg();
    }
    private void printContainerStartMsg() {
        logger.info("----------- Scrubber Container Starts   --------------");
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory queueListenerContainer(AbstractConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) { 
        connectionFactory.setAddresses(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberHosts());
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("hydra.services");
        connectionFactory.setPort(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberPort());




connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberUsername());


connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberPassword());
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());
        return factory;
    }

 @Bean
 MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(EPPQ2Subscriber receiver) {
     return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
 }

 /*@Bean
 MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapterWithChanel(EPPQ2ChanelAwareSubscriber receiverChanel) {
     return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiverChanel);
 }*/

 @Bean
    public ErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler(fatalExceptionStrategy());
    }

 @Bean
 public  ScrubberFatalExceptionStrategy fatalExceptionStrategy() {
     return new ScrubberFatalExceptionStrategy();
 }
```

}

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class EPPQ2ListenerConfigurer implements RabbitListenerConfigurer{

    public EPPQ2ListenerConfigurer(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {


registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory());
        }

        @Bean
        MessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory() {
            DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
            messageHandlerMethodFactory.setMessageConverter(consumerJackson2MessageConverter());
            return messageHandlerMethodFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public MappingJackson2MessageConverter consumerJackson2MessageConverter() {
            return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        }

    }

@Component
public class ScrubberFatalExceptionStrategy extends ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.DefaultExceptionStrategy {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScrubberFatalExceptionStrategy.class);

    @Override
    public boolean isFatal(Throwable t) {
        if (t instanceof ListenerExecutionFailedException) {
            ListenerExecutionFailedException lefe = 

(ListenerExecutionFailedException) t;
                logger.error("Failed to process inbound message from queue "
                        + lefe.getFailedMessage().getMessageProperties().getConsumerQueue()
                        + "; failed message: " + lefe.getFaile
at 
dMessage(), t);
            }
            return super.isFatal(t);
        }
    }
```

When I send the invalid json message I am expecting my handler to be called But handler is not called.

Log Message :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportInvalidEOF(ParserMinimalBase.java:618)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._handleEOF(ParserBase.java:485)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._eofAsNextChar(ParserBase.java:497)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2933)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextFieldName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:964)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:512)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:369)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
[30m
```

Could some one guide me how can I implement error handler.

---

Edit - 2 More stack trace.

```
 [30m2019-03-25 08:41:23,159[0;39m [39mDEBUG[0;39m [[34mSimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-5[0;39m] [33morg.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter[0;39m: Processing [GenericMessage [payload=byte[1918], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=hydra.Syphon.q1, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=hydra.Syphon.q1, amqp_redelivered=false, id=74e9f222-4ce9-a854-0f2a-35feac99bfca, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-pu7gaBgwJDeCzJMKKOZg3Q, timestamp=1553521283156}]]
[30m2019-03-25 08:41:23,305[0;39m [39mDEBUG[0;39m [[34mSimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-5[0;39m] [33morg.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod[0;39m: Could not resolve parameter [0] in public void com.discover.dftp.scrubber.subscriber.EPPQ2Subscriber.receiveMessage(com.discover.dftp.scrubber.domain.Message,com.rabbitmq.client.Channel,java.lang.String,org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageProperties): Could not read JSON: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (byte[])"{
  "HEADER": {
      "RETRY_COUNT":0,
      "PUBLISH_EVENT_TYPE":"AUTH"
  },
  "PAYLOAD":{
  "MTI": "100",
  "MTI_REQUEST": "100",
  "MERCHANT_TYPE": "5311",
"[truncated 1418 bytes]; line: 6, column: 13])
 at [Source: (byte[])"{
  "HEADER": {
      "RETRY_COUNT":0,
      "PUBLISH_EVENT_TYPE":"AUTH"
  },
  "PAYLOAD":{
  "MTI": "100",
  "MTI_REQUEST": "100",
"[truncated 1418 bytes]; line: 55, column: 24] (through reference chain: com.discover.dftp.scrubber.domain.Message["PAYLOAD"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (byte[])"{
  "HEADER": {
      "RETRY_COUNT":0,
      "PUBLISH_EVENT_TYPE":"AUTH"
  },
  "PAYLOAD":{
  "MTI": "100",
  "MTI_REQUEST": "100",
  "PAN": "6011000000000000",
  "PROCCODE": "00",
  "PROCCODE_REQUEST": "00",
  "FROM_ACCOUNT": "00",
  "TO_ACCOUNT": "00",
  "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": "000000000100",
  "TRANSMISSION_MMDDHHMMSS": "0518202930",
  "STAN": "000001",
  "LOCALTIME_HHMMSS": "010054",
  "LOCALDATE_YYMMDD": "180522",
  "EXPIRATION_DATE_YYMM": "2302",
  "MERCHANT_TYPE": "5311",
"[truncated 1418 bytes]; line: 6, column: 13])
 at [Source: (byte[])"{
  "HEADER": {
      "RETRY_COUNT":0,
      "PUBLISH_EVENT_TYPE":"AUTH"
  },
  "PAYLOAD":{
  "MTI": "100",
  "MTI_REQUEST": "100",
  "MERCHANT_TYPE": "5311",
"[truncated 1418 bytes]; line: 55, column: 24] (through reference chain: com.discover.dftp.scrubber.domain.Message["PAYLOAD"])
[30m2019-03-25 08:41:23,309[0;39m [31mWARN [0;39m [[34mSimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-5[0;39m] [33morg.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler[0;39m: Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.discover.dftp.scrubber.subscriber.EPPQ2Subscriber.receiveMessage(com.discover.dftp.scrubber.domain.Message,com.rabbitmq.client.Channel,java.lang.String,org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageProperties)]
Bean [com.discover.dftp.scrubber.subscriber.EPPQ2Subscriber@56994b]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:193)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1473)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1405)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (byte[])"{
  "HEADER": {
      "RETRY_COUNT":0,
      "PUBLISH_EVENT_TYPE":"AUTH"
  },
  "PAYLOAD":{
  "MTI": "100",
  "MTI_REQUEST": "100",
  truncated 1418 bytes]; line: 55, column: 24] (through reference chain: com.discover.dftp.scrubber.domain.Message["PAYLOAD"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (byte[])"{
  "HEADER": {
      "RETRY_COUNT":0,
      "PUBLISH_EVENT_TYPE":"AUTH"
  },
  "PAYLOAD":{
  "MTI": "100",
  "MTI_REQUEST": "100",

"[truncated 1418 bytes]; line: 6, column: 13])
 at [Source: (byte[])"{
  "HEADER": {
      "RETRY_COUNT":0,
      "PUBLISH_EVENT_TYPE":"AUTH"
  },
  "PAYLOAD":{
  "MTI": "100",
  "MTI_REQUEST": "100",
  truncated 1418 bytes]; line: 55, column: 24] (through reference chain: com.discover.dftp.scrubber.domain.Message["PAYLOAD"])
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:234)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:137)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:117)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:147)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:49)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:190)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (byte[])"{
  "HEADER": {
      "RETRY_COUNT":0,
      "PUBLISH_EVENT_TYPE":"AUTH"
  },
  "PAYLOAD":{
  "MTI": "100",
  "MTI_REQUEST": "100",

"[truncated 1418 bytes]; line: 6, column: 13])
 at [Source: (byte[])"{
  "HEADER": {
      "RETRY_COUNT":0,
      "PUBLISH_EVENT_TYPE":"AUTH"
  },
  "PAYLOAD":{
  "MTI": "100",
  "MTI_REQUEST": "100",

"[truncated 1418 bytes]; line: 55, column: 24] (through reference chain: com.discover.dftp.scrubber.domain.Message["PAYLOAD"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1711)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:371)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3121)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:221)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (byte[])"{
  "HEADER": {
      "RETRY_COUNT":0,
      "PUBLISH_EVENT_TYPE":"AUTH"
  },
  "PAYLOAD":{
  "MTI": "100",

"[truncated 1418 bytes]; line: 6, column: 13])
 at [Source: (byte[])"{
  "HEADER": {
      "RETRY_COUNT":0,
      "PUBLISH_EVENT_TYPE":"AUTH"
  },
  "PAYLOAD":{
  "MTI": "100",
  "MTI_REQUEST": "100",

"[truncated 1418 bytes]; line: 55, column: 1949]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportInvalidEOF(ParserMinimalBase.java:618)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._handleEOF(ParserBase.java:485)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._eofAsNextChar(ParserBase.java:497)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2933)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextFieldName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:964)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:512)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:369)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
[30m2019-03-25 08:41:23,310[0;39m [31mWARN [0;39m [[34mSimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-5[0;39m] [33morg.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler$DefaultExceptionStrategy[0;39m: Fatal message conversion error; message rejected; it will be dropped or routed to a dead letter exchange, if so configured: (Body:'[B@1707e57(byte[1918])' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=hydra.Syphon.q1, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-pu7gaBgwJDeCzJMKKOZg3Q, consumerQueue=hydra.Syphon.q1])
[30m2019-03-25 08:41:23,311[0;39m [1;31mERROR[0;39m [[34mSimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-5[0;39m] [33morg.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer[0;39m: Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and the error handler threw an exception
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Error Handler converted exception to fatal
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleError(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1626)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.discover.dftp.scrubber.subscriber.EPPQ2Subscriber.receiveMessage(com.discover.dftp.scrubber.domain.Message,com.rabbitmq.client.Channel,java.lang.String,org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageProperties)]
Bean [com.discover.dftp.scrubber.subscriber.EPPQ2Subscriber@56994b]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:193)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1473)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1405)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (byte[])"{
```

Comment: May we have more stack trace from you? I wonder what part of listener container is involved in the producing error.

Comment: @ArtemBilan  I have attached more trace for reference

Comment: How do you use that `queueListenerContainer`? It must be explicitly configured on your `@RabbitListener.containerFactory()`

Comment: Yes sir, This works now. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you define a custom container factory like yours:

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory queueListenerContainer(
```

Then you need to be sure that you really use it in the target `@RabbitListener`.

See its JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * The bean name of the {@link org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerContainerFactory}
 * to use to create the message listener container responsible to serve this endpoint.
 * <p>If not specified, the default container factory is used, if any.
 * @return the {@link org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerContainerFactory}
 * bean name.
 */
String containerFactory() default "";
```

See Docs on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/#async-annotation-driven